# jQuery Supersize play button and tray down button not showing up

Tags: jquery, wordpress, supersized

I have integrated Supersized 3.2.7 - Fullscreen Slideshow jQuery Plugin into a custom WordPress theme. I am using WordPress 3.4.2. Everything about the slideshow is working great except that when I click the pause button I get a missing play button (play.png). This also happens when I click the tray open button, the tray down button (button-tray-down.png) is missing. Here is a link to the page: http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/views/

When I check on the path to these buttons in the source I see img/button-tray-down.png and img/play.png. Obviously this is the wrong path but I can't figure out how to get it to use the correct path to the images.

I have spent hours googling but not found any answers yet. Here is my code that calls the supersized function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){

        $.supersized({

            // Functionality
            slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
            autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
            start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
            stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
            random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
            slide_interval          :   6000,       // Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   2000,       // Speed of transition
            new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
            pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
            keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
            performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
            image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

            // Size & Position                         
            min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
            min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
            vertical_center         :   0,          // Vertically center background
            horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
            fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
            fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
            fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

            // Components                           
            slide_links             :   false,  // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
            thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
            thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                {image : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-5.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-5.jpg', url : ''},
                                                {image : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-4.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-4.jpg', url : ''},  
                                                {image : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-3.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-3.jpg', url : ''},
                                                {image : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-2.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-2.jpg', url : ''},
                                                {image : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-1.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'http://dev4.mccawphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/amenities-1.jpg', url : ''},


                                        ],

            // Theme Options               
            progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
            mouse_scrub             :   0

        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the path to the images in your JavaScript under vars:

```
   image_path: "img/"
```

Change this to:

```
   image_path: "/wp-content/themes/residence-xxv/images/"
```

Comment: I just tried adding 
    image_path:"/wp-content/themes/residence-xxv/images/" to the above javascript but it didn't work. Am I not adding it to the correct javascript?

Comment: Ah, it's not actually in your code at all. It's hard-coded into `supersized.shutter.min.js`. You will either have to replace it in there, or edit the unminified version of this JavaScript file and use that.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much! I don't really like editing the actual plugin file. I wonder why it is done that way. Seems like you should be able to change the image_path like above in your call to initialize the function. If you know of a better way to fix this I would appreciate knowing it. In the meantime it is working now. Thanks again!